# How to get data of people who likes my facebook posts using Graph API in android

Tags: android, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I am new to Facebook graph API. How can I get the list of all posts or limited number of posts and list of those people who like my status or pictures in android.
Thanks in advance Sorry for poor english.

**Edited**

I have done quite a work but Now i am getting using queries like this.
1) me/posts (data of all posts)
2) id/likes/id?fields{name,id}(id= post_id)
I am using **Graph API Explorer** to get required JSON but i am not **able** to get data in one line query like **me/posts/id/likes/id?fields{name,id}**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [/{object-id}/likes](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/object/likes) API which returns an array of [User object](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/)s representing each of the people who liked the object along with total likes.

You should use [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/graph/) from [Facebook SDK for Android](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android). Before you begin, set up:

- [Facebook Android SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/)
- [Facebook Login for Android](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/login-with-facebook/)
- [Permissions on Android](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/permissions)

Then use **[GraphRequest(AccessToken, String, Bundle, HttpMethod, Callback)](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/GraphRequest/)** to make the request and handle result in the callback.

> **GraphRequest(AccessToken, String, Bundle, HttpMethod, Callback)**
>
> Constructs a request with a specific access token, graph path,
> parameters, and HTTP method. An access token need not be provided, in
> which case the request is sent without an access token and thus is not
> executed in the context of any particular user. Only certain graph
> requests can be expected to succeed in this case.
>
> Depending on the httpMethod parameter, the object at the graph path
> may be retrieved, created, or deleted.

```
/* make the API call */
new GraphRequest(
    AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
    "/{object-id}/likes",
    null,
    HttpMethod.GET,
    new GraphRequest.Callback() {
        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
            /* handle the result */
        }
    }
).executeAsync();
```

Comment: Thnx It Help me a bit :) But still working to find a solution

Comment: Pls update where you're stuck with some code samples so that community can help you better

Comment: Thnx I solved it by simply using Nested queries of Graph APi :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm one of the co-founders of [Kither](https://www.kither.io), a platform for checking all of your Facebook stats. We have added many features which requires to fetch all of our user's posts likes.

Assuming you're familiar with Facebook's android SDK, you can call **`/{post-id}/likes`**, to get likes on that post. But remember, Facebook uses pagination on likes if there are more than 1,000 of them.

Now, In this case you'll need to call the next page url.

[image: Facebook Likes' pagination]

You'll need to call the **next** url unless you've got all the likes. *(you won't find any **next** field if there are no more likes)*

To get how many people have liked that post (i.e. count), you don't need to page through results. You can simply use **`/{post-id}/likes?summary=true`** and you'll get an extra field containing all likes' summary, including their count.

Same can be done with **comments** and recently added, **reactions**.

Answer (score 2):

An update to the above answer:

FB API is not providing likes in deatils anymore.
[image]

However, adding summary still gives the total counts of likes, which we can also get form reactions(by adding type to it).

If anybody finds another method to get the people who liked the post, then kindly update.

**Note: The screenshot shows API version 2.10, however, behaviour is same on 2.12 as well**